# Java: converting each letter into the number for example a = 1, b = 2, c = 3

Tags: java, arrays, char, int

```
char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'...};

int number = 0;

char input = console.nextLine().charAt(0);

for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
   if(Character.isLetter(alphabet[i])) {
      number = i;
   }
}
System.out.println(number);
```

I want each letter to be converted into a number for example

> a = 1;  b = 2;  c = 3...  and so on.

but it keeps turning 'number' into 10 for some reason
help pls
my code is a complete mess

Comment: Are you using an IDE? An IDE would warn you that your input variable is unused.

Answer (score 1):

To store key - value pairs, you can use a map. An example of a key value pair would be 'a' and 1.

Create a map and populate it with your key value pairs.

```
Map<Character, Integer> letterMap = new HashMap<>();
letterMap.put('a', 1);
letterMap.put('b', 2);
...
```

Afterwards, you can retrieve the value for the character with a simple "get" operation.

```
char input = console.nextLine().charAt(0);
if(Character.isLetter(input)) {
    int number = letterMap.get(input); //Simple get operation
    System.out.println(number);
} else {
    System.out.println("You did not input a lowercase letter.");
}
```

Comment: `map` implementation was very obvious and expected as you did. :)

Comment: Thanks for checking it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do like this

```
char ch = 'z';
int position = ch - 'a' + 1;
System.out.print(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clearer in what you are trying to accomplish. What do you want to do with these numerical positions of alphabet letters? Are you obtaining user input? Something like this may be what you're looking for:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
System.out.println("Enter string: ");
String input = "";
while(keyboard.hasNextLine()) {
    input += keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
}

for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(alphabet.indexOf(input.charAt(i))+1+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the characters are in order in the ASCII character set, just subtract `a` from each and add 1.

```
char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'};
for (char c : alphabet) {
   System.out.println(c - 'a' + 1);
}
```